# How to sort strings by their first char in pascal?

Tags: string, sorting, pascal

I believe that the question is pretty clear.
So, how to sort strings by their first char in pascal?
Since as far as I know pascal has no native sorting functions there should be a way to to transfer letters in to digits and then sort them some how... Anyhow that is only by guess.
Thanks for the answers in advance ;)

Comment: And what do you want to happen if the first char is identical? What kind of string(ansi, utf16,...)? Which implementation of pascal?

Comment: If the first chars match, it would be nice that it would be sorted be the second char thou that is optional. Ansi string type will do. In if I understood your last question right the answer to it should be: I am using Turbo Pascal.

Comment: And what ordering of chars do you want? By ordinal, or something more fancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
program test;

var
  nr:Integer;
  mystrings:array [0..100] of string;
  i:Integer;
  tmp,tmp2,tmp3:String;
begin
  WriteLn('Please input number of strings');
  ReadLn(nr); //max 100 strings
  for i:=0 to nr - 1 do
  begin
      str(i,tmp3);
      Write('String['+tmp3+'] = ');ReadLn(mystrings[i]);
  end;

  // Now we sort the strings

  i:=0;
  repeat
    tmp:=UpperCase(mystrings[i]);
    tmp2:=UpperCase(mystrings[i+1]);
    if tmp[1]>tmp2[1] then
    begin
        tmp:=mystrings[i];
        mystrings[i]:=mystrings[i+1];
        mystrings[i+1]:=tmp;
        i:=-1;
    end;
    Inc(i);
  until i=nr -1 ;

  //Display strings sorted
  for i:=0 to nr - 1 do
  begin
      WriteLn(mystrings[i]);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Wow! It was a real surprise that strings are actually arrays of chars which can be compared to each other that easily. Thanks!